# Is this possible while using jquery validation plugins with asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I want to pass the name attribute of the fileds like this...

```
rules: {               
             '($(txtFName).attr('name'))': {
             required: true,
             No_Spl_Char: "DFT"
             }
    },
```

This is not working and I can't seem to find any other way to pass the name attribute..I have used UniqueID also to get the name attribute but the form fields are in diferent controls so it is not working. can any one suggest the smarter way to get the name attribute and pass. Help is always appreciated.

I have multiple rules and messages...and I can't use UniqueID anymore because someof the fileds are in different controls not in the same controls.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // validate the comment form when it is submitted
    $("#aspnetForm").validate({
    onfocusout: function(element) { $(element).valid(); },
    success: function(label) {
       label.addClass("validfld");
    },
    validClass: "validfld",  
    rules: {
            <%=txtFNameRoom.UniqueID%>: {
             required: true,
             No_Spl_Char: true
             },
             <%=txtLNameRoom.UniqueID%>: {
             required: true,
             No_Spl_Char: true
             },
             <%=txtEmail.UniqueID%>: {
             required: true,
             email: true
             },
             <%=ddlCountry.UniqueID%>: {
             required: true,
             valueNotEquals: "DFT"
             },
             <%=ddlMobileNumber.UniqueID%>: {
             required: true,
             valueNotEquals: "DFT"
             },
             <%=txtTelephone.UniqueID%>: {
             required: true,
             digits: true
             },
             <%=DropDownList1.UniqueID%>: {
             required: true,
             valueNotEquals: "DFT"
             }
    },
    messages: {
        <%=txtFNameRoom.UniqueID%>:{
            required: "Please enter your firstname.",
            No_Spl_Char: "Special Characters are not allowed."
        },
        <%=txtLNameRoom.UniqueID%>:{
            required: "Please enter your lastname.",
            No_Spl_Char: "Special Characters are not allowed."
        },
        <%=txtEmail.UniqueID%>:{
        required: "Please enter your email.",
        email: "Please enter valid email."
        },
        <%=ddlCountry.UniqueID%>:{
        required: "Please select your country.",
        valueNotEquals: "Please select your country."
        },
        <%=ddlMobileNumber.UniqueID%>: "Please enter your country code.",
        <%=txtTelephone.UniqueID%>:{
        required: "Please enter your email.",
        digits: "Please enter only digits."
        },
        <%=DropDownList1.UniqueID%>: "Please select your bed preference."

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
var rulesObject = {};
rulesObject[$(txtFName).attr('name')] = {
   required: true,
   No_Spl_Char: "DFT"
};
rulesObject['<%=txtFNameRoom.UniqueID%>'] = {
    required: true,
    No_Spl_Char: true
};
rulesObject['<%=ddlCountry.UniqueID%>'] = {
    required: true,
    valueNotEquals: "DFT"
};
//etc...


//then

$("#aspnetForm").validate({
     //......
     rules: rulesObject
     //......
```

Comment: what if there are multiple rules...? I have modified the question to include multiple rules.

Comment: your help is like taking me from hell to heaven.....it is working absolutely fine...I have created the messageobject as well and tested ..it is working fine....Thanks a lot for your help! how can I buy you a beer?  :)